# UICollectionView targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset: Overridden by UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I have a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout when I insert some items at the top I calculate the appropriate and return it from `targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:`.

The problem is on the first insertion batch updates at the top the `UIScrollView` in method called `_smoothScrollDisplayLink:`override the contentOffset from the value returned from `targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:` by a value that's completely off (I return for example 900s it overrides it to 500s)

BUT

On the following insertion batch updates the values set by the `UISCrollView` method is very reasonable.

More info #1:

I try to insert items at the top but keep the scrolling position constant so basically I set the content offset to the current contentOffset + delta in height between before and after the insertion updates

More info #2:
Here's some real values I logged:

```
current offset=95.500000, newHeight=1835.007812, oldHeight=936.003906
new offset = 994.503906
set content offset: 550.000000 before: 994.503906  (by _smoothScrollDisplayLink:)

current offset=95.500000, newHeight=2771.011719, oldHeight=1835.007812
new offset = 1031.503906
set content offset: 1026.500000 before: 1031.503906 (by _smoothScrollDisplayLink:)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got a same problem. Try this hack:

1. In your `flowLayout` save last target `contentOffset`:

   ```
   - (CGPoint)targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:(CGPoint)proposedContentOffset
   {
       CGPoint contentOffset = [super targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:proposedContentOffset];

       _lastTargetContentOffset = contentOffset;

       return contentOffset;
   }
   ```
2. In your `collectionView` override method `setContentOffset` like this:

   ```
   - (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset
   {
       if (self.contentSize.height != self.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height)
       {
           MyCollectionViewFlowLayout * myCollectionLayout =  (MyCollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionViewLayout;
           NSParameterAssert([myCollectionLayout isKindOfClass:MyCollectionViewFlowLayout.class]);
           [super setContentOffset:myCollectionLayout.lastTargetContentOffset];
       }
       else
       {
           [super setContentOffset:contentOffset];
       }
   }
   ```